# How to calculate the optimal quantity of a independent variable to get the minimum model output?

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, model

In R I made a multiple linear regression model with 10 variables, after I have the model with the coefficients I would like to know how to calculate the miminum value of each independent variable that would give me the global minimum value of the output "y" from the model?

I tried optim package which I read does this but I get an error

```
 Error in fn(par, ...) : could not find function "fn"
```

```
### calculate model
fit <- lm(Y ~., data=df2)

### create equation in function with parameters and coefficients to get ### global mínimum and with which values each value gets to that mínimum

f <- function(X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9) -210.50200438 - 1.08319034 * X +  0.07467384 * X1  + 0.02106764 * X2 + 0.08280658 * X3 + 2.07585559 * X4 + 5.09223561 * X5 + -7.57592770 * X6 + 1.62970544 * X7 + 0.45169896 * X8  - 0.32157245 * X9

### Variables
X <- seq(19,75,by=1)
X1 <- seq(3780,9183,by=100)
X2 <- seq(7534,15840,by=100)
X3 <- seq(2810,5100,by=100)
X4 <- seq(185,596,by=1)
X5 <- seq(1.20,48.1,by=0.1)
X6 <- seq(38,78,by=1)
X7 <- seq(33,100,by=1)
X8 <- seq(160,358,by=1)
X9 <- seq(42,458,by=1)
z <- outer(X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,f) 
optim(X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,f)
```

I want to know what is the global minimum of "y" and the values for each independent variables in order to get to that minimum, however I get that mistake with optim, if that is not what I should use please tell me how could I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Since yours is a linear model and your restrictions are independent of each other, the value of each variable that gives you the minimum will be at one of the ends of your possible options, so you don't need to use an optimization function. Ex: the variable X has a negative parameter, so you want the biggest X you can. Therefore, X = 75, X1 = 3780, X2 = 7534, etc will generate the minimum given your restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

As shared in the comments by @Luis, take the minimum value of your variable if the coefficient is positive and the maximum value if the coefficient is negative.

```
### Variables
X <- seq(19, 75, by = 1)
X1 <- seq(3780, 9183, by = 100)
X2 <- seq(7534, 15840, by = 100)
X3 <- seq(2810, 5100, by = 100)
X4 <- seq(185, 596, by = 1)
X5 <- seq(1.20, 48.1, by = 0.1)
X6 <- seq(38, 78, by = 1)
X7 <- seq(33, 100, by = 1)
X8 <- seq(160, 358, by = 1)
X9 <- seq(42, 458, by = 1)

f <- function(X, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9)
  (- 210.50200438 
   - 1.08319034 * X 
   + 0.07467384 * X1  
   + 0.02106764 * X2 
   + 0.08280658 * X3 
   + 2.07585559 * X4 
   + 5.09223561 * X5
   - 7.57592770 * X6 
   + 1.62970544 * X7 
   + 0.45169896 * X8  
   - 0.32157245 * X9)

f(max(X), min(X1), min(X2), min(X3), min(X4),  min(X5), max(X6), min(X7), min(X8), max(X9))
```